# T-SQL Set Variable IF record exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server. I want to set a variable based on a select, but only if there is a record in `table1`. If there is no record, then just return 0.99

I'm using this code, but it's not working:

```
DECLARE @Threshold AS FLOAT

SET @Threshold = IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * 
                            FROM [DB]..[table1] P 
                            WHERE P.RowId IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT [Value] 
    FROM [DB]..[table1]
ELSE 
    SELECT 0.99
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.

What am I missing?

Comment: Also because SQL is **orderless** you also atleast need to use a `ORDER BY` in combination with `TOP` .. edit  *"I want to set a variable based on a select, but only if there is a record in 'table1'. If there is no record,"* Well the order does not to seam to be really important in this case as it is just a record existing check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method in T-SQL is:

```
declare @Threshold float;

if (exists (select top 1 * from [DB]..[table1] P where P.RowId IS NOT NULL))
begin
    select @Threshold = [Value] 
    from [DB]..[table1]
end;
else select @Threshold = 0.99;
```

Personally, I think that is rather verbose.  You can just do:

```
declare @Threshold float;

select @Threshold = coalesce(max([Value]), 0.99)
from [DB]..[table1]
where P.RowId is not null;
```

This works because an aggregation query without a `group by` always returns one row.  If nothing matches, then the columns are `NULL`.

This is not 100% equivalent, because a row *could* exist with a `NULL` value.  This version would assign `0.99` rather than `NULL` (as yours does).  I suspect that this behavior may be what you really want.

Comment: yes you are correct - if it does exist with a null value, I still want to return 0.99.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

check below query.

```
SELECT TOP (1)
  @Threshold = ISNULL([Value], 0.99)
FROM [DB]..[table1] P
WHERE P.RowId IS NOT NULL
```